# When you use the escape key to exit something in a web browser, like a modal dialogue box, where does focus go?

Tags: html, css, browser, focus, accessibility

In most cases there doesn't seem to be any visual indication which must be difficult for users who rely on the keyboard.

This seems a really simple question but I've scoured the internet and can't find an answer.  My first idea was to use Firefox's developer tools to create a visual indication using `*some element*:focus {outline: 2px solid red;}` but of course you'd need to already know which element was receiving focus for that to work, so I tried the universal selector `*:focus {outline:2px solid red;}` but that didn't work.

So can anyone answer the seemingly simple question of what element is gaining focus ... and for bonus kudos can anyone provide a code snippet that would allow me to actually see what is happening?

Comment: Interesting question which I would also like to know the answer to. Verify that your `focus` is not being overridden by some other selector. Try `*:focus {outline:2px solid red !important;}`. This worked for me testing on random websites.

Comment: Thanks @jfeferman, that wasn't the problem but I'd forgotten that using `!important` during diagnostics is good practice; you can waste an awful lot of time if you forget. It would appear from further investigation that focus is moving outside the viewport ... I just don't know where.

Comment: If you use an accessibility technology like VoiceOver, you can visually track focus. Also, take a look at [activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement). This can give you a js handle on the focused element.

Comment: You also can check focus with javascript: `document.activeElement`

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a modal dialog box, the focus should go back to where it were before the box appeared.

For example, if the dialog box appeared upon clicking a button, the focus should return to that button when the dialog is closed, regardless of how it has been closed (mouse click or enter on a close button or escape key).

The most keyboard accessible apps and websites are those where you always know where the focus is. The blur function must be banned; it should never have existed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation where focus goes after closing the dialog.

However, the [WAI-ARIA best practices for keyboard interaction](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#keyboard-interaction-7) state the following for dialog in a note:

> When a dialog closes, focus returns to the element that invoked the dialog […]

In other words, the link or button that opened the dialog is focused.

I checked the native implementation of the HTML `<dialog>` element in Firefox and Chrome.

Chrome 78: After leaving the dialog by means of the *escape* key, focus is set back on `<body>`.

Firefox 71: Did not implement any focus logic yet. Focus is not limited to the dialog, neither is it put anywhere else after the dialog closes.

For all other UI libraries there is different ways to implement the dialog, which will result in different elements being focussed after closing:

1 Conditional rendering: The dialog doesn't even exist in the DOM if it's not visible
2 Hiding the dialog via HTML `hidden=true` or CSS only `display: none`

In case 1 focus will be set on `<body>` in Chrome and Firefox.

In case 2 both browsers keep the focus on the element inside the (now hidden) modal.

If accessibility is a concern, the evaluation of different libraries should take that into account.